# Restkit: Post an array of id's instead of the complete objects

Tags: json, post, restkit

I have a case where I need to post and array of numbers to the server side. E.g:

I have an order that have a list of products with one to many relation ships.
The question is how to post only array of id's for current order:
Now I have such result:

`{"orders":[{"id":0,"Products":[{"productId":6},{"productId":7},{"productId":5},{"productId":3}]},{"id":1,.....]}`

But I want to make it

`{"orders":[{"id":0,"Products":[6,7,5,3]},{"id":1,.....]}`

Any ideas ?

**Update 1**

I think I have found a solution

I have add method that fetch id's of my order products it's look like this

`-(NSArray *)productsIds { 
return [self.products.array valueForKeyPath:ProductAttributes.productId];
 }`

and add such a thing to my mapping code part.

```
 [orderSerializationMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"productsIds" : @"Products"}];
```

And now result is

{"orders":[{"id":5,"Products":[17,13,16,11,12,19]},......]

Answer (score 0):

You don't need add a method to fetch the id's. Setup your mapping like this:

```
[orderSerializationMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"products.productID": @"Products"}];
```